# My Android app is labeled as "already running" even after a call to finish()... why?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-emulator

In Eclipse, I load up an Android Virtual Device, and then once it's loaded and not at the lock screen, I hit "Debug" on the Eclipse toolbar.  My app runs fine (barring any errors from the last edit cycle, but that's what debugging is for).  However, after I try to end my app (by hitting the back button from the main [only] activity - I have implemented a call to finish() as the last line of onBackPressed() , even though on further research it appears that hitting the back button from the main activity implicitly calls finish() ), it appears to not end the app.

The Eclipse debug perspective's Debug pane still shows the following:

```
MyAppName [Android application]
 DalvikVM[localhost:8619]   
  Thread [<1> main] (Running)
  Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)
  Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running)
```

I am assuming the DalvikVM line is the emulator.  I do not knowingly spin up any extra threads in my app (light enough computations, so far, that I just do them all in the UI thread on button clicks, etc), so I have no idea whatsoever where Binder_1 and Binder_2 came from.

Also, when I go to debug again, thinking the app was fully shut down, the tool-tip on the debug icon is "Debug MyAppName (already running)".

Does finish() not terminate the application when it comes to Eclipse's debug hooks?  Or, is there some other method I should call from the main activity that behaves like a "terminate()", that tells Android that not only the activity, but the whole app, is finished?

Yes, I am aware that Android apps' processes are not immediately killed when running on the device during the normal life cycle.  I realize that I don't want to make my app kill its process stone cold dead when it comes to the shipped version.  However, if this is the cause of the persistent debugger tie-in, I would at least like to implement something like `if(DEBUG_MODE) trulyExit();` , either by teaching Eclipse to autokill after a finish() somehow, or by implementing some sort of trulyExit() in my main activity, to only be used during debugging.  So, if I could get a few tips on how to teach Eclipse, or how one would implement a `trulyExit()`, that'd be awesome.

My workaround currently is closing the emulator each time.  I can't think, though, that that's how you're supposed to end a debugging session...

Relevant dev environment info:

- (OS: Windows 7 Professional)
- IDE: Android Developer Tools build v22.0.1-685705

  - No additions/plugins to the ADT Eclipse, other than what Google's ADT download gives.
- Test platform: Emulator, not device

  - (the USB port on my physical device is on the fritz, I am not sure if debugging tie-ins will still misbehave on it or not.)

Comment: You can use the "terminate" (red stop button) to terminate a debug session. I don't see any reason for you to have to make a `trulyExit()` of some kind. Also, you do not need to call `finish()` in `onBackPressed()`. Backing out of an Activity implicitly finishes it.

Comment: The DalvikVM is the platform provided code which allows the underlying Linux system to execute Dalvik Byte Code.  Any application process will have one or more threads in the Binder pool for interprocess communication with the framework code - that all happens behind the scenes.